# Number of ways to park $10$ cars

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $10$ cars (5 Fords, 3 Dodges, and 2 Hondas), how many ways can the cars be parked if there are (a) $10$ spots available? (b) $15$ spots available?
My solution:

(a) ${10 \choose 5} + {5 \choose 3} + {2 \choose 2} = 252+10+1=263$

(b) ${15 \choose 5} + {10 \choose 3} + {7 \choose 2} = 3003 + 120 + 21 = 3144$

Are my solutions correct? Thanks.

Comment: Or should these numbers be multiplied?

Comment: Multiplied as you could consider a smaller number like suppose 3 spots with 2 Fords and a Dodge. There are only 3 possible combinations as wherever the Dodge is placed will force the 2 Fords to the other places whereas under your addition there would be 4 possibilities as it would be 3+1 instead of 3*1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your comment, the three binomial coefficients should be multiplied. For example, for part (a), first you are choosing $5$ spots out of $10$ for the fords, then you are choosing three spots out of the remaining five spots for your Dodges, then finally, are you choosing two spots out of the remaining two spots for your Hondas. Hence, there are
$$\binom{10}{5} \times \binom{5}{3} \times \binom{2}{2} = 2520$$
ways to park your cars. Note that the order of the brands you choose the spots for does not matter. You will always get
$$\frac{10!}{5!3!2!} = 2520$$
ways of parking the cars.

Editing to comment about part (b):

Following the same line of reasoning, we get that there are
$$\binom{15}{5} \times \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{7}{2} = \frac{15!}{5!3!2!5!}$$
ways of parking the cars. You can think of it also as there being an imaginary fourth brand of cars that occupy the five eventually empty spots.

Answer (score 0):

these numbers should be multiplied.

${10 \choose 5} \cdot { 5 \choose 3} \cdot {2 \choose 2}=\frac{10!}{5!5!}\cdot \frac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot \frac{2!}{0!2!}=\frac{10!}{5!3!2!}={10 \choose 5, 3, 2}$ the multinomial coeffecient.

Similarly, for (b) you should be taking the product to get ${15 \choose 5,3,2,5}=\frac{15!}{5!3!2!5!}$

Comment: While correct, this does not seem useful to OP because it is not detailed enough.

Comment: @RossMillikan it's actually slightly incorrect as the denominator should be $5!3!2!5!$

Answer (score 0):

In some circles this is known as the [Bookkeeper Rule](http://web.mit.edu/broder/Public/6.042-lecture-notes/lec17.pdf), which describes the number of ways to re-arrange the letters in the word "bookkeeper":

> The number of sequences with $n_1$ copies of $l_1$, $n_2$ copies of
>   $l_2$, $\ldots$, and $n_k$ copies of $l_k$ is $$\frac{(n_1 + n_2 + \ldots + n_k)!}{n_1! n_2! \ldots n_k!}$$ provided $l_1$, $\ldots$, $l_k$
>   are distinct.

You have $n_1 = 5$ (the Fords), $n_2 = 3$ (the Dodges), and $n_3 = 2$ (the Hondas).

For (a) the number of combinations is

$$\frac{(5 + 3 + 2)!}{5!3!2!} = \frac{10!}{5!3!2!} = 2520$$

For (b) you have to consider a fourth group of $n_4 = 5$ empty spots. The number of combinations is

$$\frac{(5 + 3 + 2 + 5)!}{5!3!2!5!} = \frac{15!}{5!3!2!5!} = 7567560$$